# How do I loop through a nested element in JSON using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this nested JSON in which I'm exploding the data out of. I do this via spark.sql(), but how can I pull out elements that appear multiple times? I would like to have a row for each of those specific elements.

For instance, here is a sample of my JSON file:

```
{
  "httpStatus": 200,
  "httpStatusMessage": "success",
  "timestamp": "2020-11-11T19:46:01",
  "response": {
    "header": {
      "fleetId": 10006,
      "fleetName": "Naples",
      "date": "2020-11-04T00:00:00",
      "gpsUnit": "dd",
      "speedUnit": "mph",
      "accelUnit": "g",
      "distanceUnit": "miles"
    },
    "body": {
      "dataProviders": [
        {
          "dataProviderId": 14,
          "drivers": [
            {
              "driverRef": "b119",
              "driverId": 1000611055,
              "driverFirstName": "John",
              "driverLastName": "Doedoe",
              "totalDistance": 238.87,
              "vehicles": [
                {
                  "deviceRef": null,
                  "deviceId": 0,
                  "vehicleRef": "1LNHL9DKXFG607058",
                  "vehicleId": 1000621018,
                  "trips": [
                    {
                      "tripId": "2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-10",
                      "tripDuration": 93.42,
                      "tripDistanceTravelled": 60.93,
                      "averageSpeed": 39.1,
                      "tripStart": {
                        "longitude": -81.7546463012695,
                        "latitude": 26.5263614654541,
                        "heading": 0,
                        "speed": 0,
                        "mileage": 0,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-04T15:54:11Z"
                      },
                      "tripStop": {
                        "longitude": -81.7561874389648,
                        "latitude": 26.5265655517578,
                        "heading": 0,
                        "speed": 0,
                        "mileage": 0,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-04T17:27:36.063Z"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "tripId": "2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-11",
                      "tripDuration": 60.03,
                      "tripDistanceTravelled": 32.11,
                      "averageSpeed": 32.1,
                      "tripStart": {
                        "longitude": -81.7561874389648,
                        "latitude": 26.5265655517578,
                        "heading": 0,
                        "speed": 0,
                        "mileage": 0,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-04T17:46:55.063Z"
                      },
                      "tripStop": {
                        "longitude": -81.7723388671875,
                        "latitude": 26.2240772247314,
                        "heading": 0,
                        "speed": 0,
                        "mileage": 0,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-04T18:46:57Z"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "tripId": "2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-8",
                      "tripDuration": 49.77,
                      "tripDistanceTravelled": 25.56,
                      "averageSpeed": 30.8,
                      "tripStart": {
                        "longitude": -81.7721862792969,
                        "latitude": 26.2239742279053,
                        "heading": 0,
                        "speed": 5.6,
                        "mileage": 0,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-04T14:29:41Z"
                      },
                      "tripStop": {
                        "longitude": -81.7538528442383,
                        "latitude": 26.5260028839111,
                        "heading": 0,
                        "speed": 5.6,
                        "mileage": 0,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-04T15:19:27Z"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "deviceRef": null,
                  "deviceId": 0,
                  "vehicleRef": "1GNSCGKCXKR180027",
                  "vehicleId": 1000621026,
                  "trips": [
                    {
                      "tripId": "2020-11-04-10006-1000616026-2",
                      "tripDuration": 59.95,
                      "tripDistanceTravelled": 30.41,
                      "averageSpeed": 30.4,
                      "tripStart": {
                        "longitude": -81.754524230957,
                        "latitude": 26.5265655517578,
                        "heading": 0,
                        "speed": 0,
                        "mileage": 0,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-04T01:23:54.063Z"
                      },
                      "tripStop": {
                        "longitude": -81.7721328735352,
                        "latitude": 26.2240772247314,
                        "heading": 0,
                        "speed": 0,
                        "mileage": 0,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-04T02:23:51.063Z"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There is three instances of trips and within trips there are three instances of tripId, tripDuration, etc...

As I explode the data out I'm starting to get all the data in an array and I need to pull that out properly but not sure how to pull out that data and store it in its own row, matching it with the parent data.

Here is my sample code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

json_df = spark.read.json('/user/myuser/json_directory/sample.json')

json_df.printSchema()

json_df.createOrReplaceTempView('test_dictionary')

spark.sql('''select * from test_dictionary''').show()


spark.sql('''select
    httpStatus
    , httpStatusMessage
    , test.dataProviderId
    , tmp1.driverFirstName
    , tmp1.driverId
    , tmp1.driverLastName
    , tmp1.driverRef
    , tmp1.totalDistance
    , tmp2.deviceId
    , tmp2.vehicleId
    , tmp2.vehicleRef
    , tmp3.averageSpeed
    , tmp3.tripDistanceTravelled
    , tmp3.tripDuration
    , tmp3.tripId
    from test_dictionary
    lateral view outer explode (response.body.dataProviders)a as test
    lateral view outer explode (response.body.dataProviders.drivers)b as tmp1
    lateral view outer explode (tmp1.vehicles)c as tmp2
    lateral view outer explode (tmp2.trips)d as tmp3''').show()
```

results look like so:

```
root
 |-- httpStatus: long (nullable = true)
 |-- httpStatusMessage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- response: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dataProviders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dataProviderId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- drivers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- driverFirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- driverId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- driverLastName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- driverRef: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- totalDistance: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- vehicles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- deviceId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- deviceRef: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- trips: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- averageSpeed: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tripDistanceTravelled: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tripDuration: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tripId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tripStart: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- heading: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- mileage: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- speed: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tripStop: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- heading: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- mileage: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- speed: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- vehicleId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- vehicleRef: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accelUnit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- distanceUnit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fleetId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fleetName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- gpsUnit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- speedUnit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)


+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|httpStatus|httpStatusMessage|            response|          timestamp|
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|       200|          success|[[[[14, [[Eric, 1...|2020-11-11T19:46:01|
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+

+----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|httpStatus|httpStatusMessage|dataProviderId|driverFirstName|    driverId|driverLastName|driverRef|totalDistance|deviceId|           vehicleId|          vehicleRef|      averageSpeed|tripDistanceTravelled|        tripDuration|              tripId|
+----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|       200|          success|            14|         [John]|[1000611055]|      [Doedoe]|   [b119]|     [238.87]|  [0, 0]|[1000621018, 1000...|[1LNHL9DKXFG60705...|[39.1, 32.1, 30.8]| [60.93, 32.11, 25...|[93.42, 60.03, 49...|[2020-11-04-10006...|
|       200|          success|            14|         [John]|[1000611055]|      [Doedoe]|   [b119]|     [238.87]|  [0, 0]|[1000621018, 1000...|[1LNHL9DKXFG60705...|            [30.4]|              [30.41]|             [59.95]|[2020-11-04-10006...|
+----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+------------+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

How do I get my results to look like so?:

```
httpStatus| httpStatusMessage|  dataProviderId| driverFirstName driverId    driverLastName  driverRef|  totalDistance|  deviceId    vehicleId   vehicleRef  averageSpeed    tripDistanceTravelled   tripDuration    tripId  tripStartLongitude  latitude    heading speed   mileage timestamp   tripstoplongitude   latitude    heading speed   mileage timestamp
200 success 14  John    1000611055  Doedoe  b119    238.87  0   1000621018  1LNHL9DKXFG607058   39.1    60.93   93.42   2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-10" -81 26  0   0   0   2020-11-04T15:54:11Z    -81.75618744    26.52656555 0   0   0   2020-11-04T17:27:36.063Z
200 success 14  John    1000611055  Doedoe  b119    238.87  0   1000621018  1LNHL9DKXFG607058   32.1    32.11   60.03   2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-11  -81.7   26.5    0   0   0   2020-11-04T17:46:55.063Z    -81.77  26.22   0   0   0   2020-11-04T18:46:57Z
200 success 14  John    1000611055  Doedoe  b119    238.87  0   1000621018  1LNHL9DKXFG607058   30.8    25.56   49.77   2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-8"  -81.7   26.2    0   5.6 0   2020-11-04T14:29:41Z    -81.74567899    26.52098    0   5.6 0   2020-11-04T15:19:27Z
200 success 14  John    1000611055  Doedoe  b119    238.87  0   1000621026  1GNSCGKCXKR180027   30.4    30.41   59.95   2020-11-04-10006-1000616026-2   -81.7   26.5265 0   0   0   2020-11-04T01:23:54.063Z"   -81.7721328 26.22407722 0   0   0   2020-11-04T02:23:51.063Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below `SQL`.

Explode all `Array` type columns.

```
spark.sql('''
    select 
        httpStatus,
        httpStatusMessage,
        dataProviders.dataProviderId, 
        drivers.driverFirstName, 
        drivers.driverId, 
        drivers.driverLastName, 
        drivers.driverRef, 
        drivers.totalDistance, 
        vehicles.deviceId, 
        vehicles.vehicleId, 
        vehicles.vehicleRef, 
        trips.averageSpeed, 
        trips.tripDistanceTravelled, 
        trips.tripDuration, 
        trips.tripId,
        trips.tripStart.longitude as tripStart_longitude, // Added tripStart as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStart.latitude as tripStart_latitude,   // Added tripStart as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStart.heading as tripStart_heading,     // Added tripStart as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStart.speed as tripStart_speed,         // Added tripStart as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStart.mileage as tripStart_mileage,     // Added tripStart as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStart.timestamp as tripStart_timestamp, // Added tripStart as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStop.longitude as tripStop_longitude,   // Added tripStop as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStop.latitude as tripStop_latitude,     // Added tripStop as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStop.heading as tripStop_heading,       // Added tripStop as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStop.speed as tripStop_speed,           // Added tripStop as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStop.mileage as tripStop_mileage,       // Added tripStop as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
        trips.tripStop.timestamp as tripStop_timestamp    // Added tripStop as prefix because tripStart & tripStop has same columns.
    from test_dictionary 
    lateral view outer explode (response.body.dataProviders) tbl_dataProviders as dataProviders // for dataProviders details
    lateral view outer explode (dataProviders.drivers) dataProviders_drivers as drivers // for drivers details
    lateral view outer explode (drivers.vehicles) drivers_vehicles as vehicles // for vehicles details
    lateral view outer explode (vehicles.trips) vehicles_trips as trips // for trips details
''').show(false)
```

**Final Output**

```
+----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+----------+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+------------+------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+
|httpStatus|httpStatusMessage|dataProviderId|driverFirstName|driverId  |driverLastName|driverRef|totalDistance|deviceId|vehicleId |vehicleRef       |averageSpeed|tripDistanceTravelled|tripDuration|tripId                        |tripStart_longitude|tripStart_latitude|tripStart_heading|tripStart_speed|tripStart_mileage|tripStart_timestamp     |tripStop_longitude|tripStop_latitude|tripStop_heading|tripStop_speed|tripStop_mileage|tripStop_timestamp      |
+----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+----------+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+------------+------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+
|200       |success          |14            |John           |1000611055|Doedoe        |b119     |238.87       |0       |1000621018|1LNHL9DKXFG607058|39.1        |60.93                |93.42       |2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-10|-81.7546463012695  |26.5263614654541  |0                |0.0            |0                |2020-11-04T15:54:11Z    |-81.7561874389648 |26.5265655517578 |0               |0.0           |0               |2020-11-04T17:27:36.063Z|
|200       |success          |14            |John           |1000611055|Doedoe        |b119     |238.87       |0       |1000621018|1LNHL9DKXFG607058|32.1        |32.11                |60.03       |2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-11|-81.7561874389648  |26.5265655517578  |0                |0.0            |0                |2020-11-04T17:46:55.063Z|-81.7723388671875 |26.2240772247314 |0               |0.0           |0               |2020-11-04T18:46:57Z    |
|200       |success          |14            |John           |1000611055|Doedoe        |b119     |238.87       |0       |1000621018|1LNHL9DKXFG607058|30.8        |25.56                |49.77       |2020-11-04-10006-1000616018-8 |-81.7721862792969  |26.2239742279053  |0                |5.6            |0                |2020-11-04T14:29:41Z    |-81.7538528442383 |26.5260028839111 |0               |5.6           |0               |2020-11-04T15:19:27Z    |
|200       |success          |14            |John           |1000611055|Doedoe        |b119     |238.87       |0       |1000621026|1GNSCGKCXKR180027|30.4        |30.41                |59.95       |2020-11-04-10006-1000616026-2 |-81.754524230957   |26.5265655517578  |0                |0.0            |0                |2020-11-04T01:23:54.063Z|-81.7721328735352 |26.2240772247314 |0               |0.0           |0               |2020-11-04T02:23:51.063Z|
+----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+----------+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+------------+------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I don't see any difference from what I had to what you had. How did you get each of the arrays to explode? You used outer explode just like I did.

Comment: Compare these two line with above solution ```lateral view outer explode (response.body.dataProviders)a as test
    lateral view outer explode (response.body.dataProviders.drivers)b as tmp1```

Comment: It should be something like ```lateral view outer explode (response.body.dataProviders)a as test
    lateral view outer explode (test.drivers)b as tmp1```

Comment: just note, ```dataProviders``` & ```drivers``` both are array type. If you want to access ```drivers``` columns you need to explode ```dataProviders``` first and then explode ```drivers``` or explode twice if you use like this -  ```dataProviders.drivers```

Comment: Ahh okay! Now that makes sense. Thank you!!

Comment: It makes sense now. Just one last question, how do I get the header info out? I can't pull response.header.accelUnit because header isn't an array, but a struct type.

Comment: use ```response.header.*``` to get all columns from the struct.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful